# Maven not taking the complete path in developer connection of scm

Tags: git, maven, github, maven-3

I am working on a build on Maven and I had specified the path in scm as follows

```
 <scm>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:[fetch=]file:///C:/official/gitrepo/.git[push=]file:///C:/official/gitrepo/.git</developerConnection>
         <tag>gitmodule</tag>
      </scm>
```

During Build maven starts complaining about

```
fatal: 'C:/official' does not appear to be a git repository
```

I am still could not figure out why maven is taking only till `'C:/official'` instead of taking full path

Am I missing something .Any light on this will be helpful

Comment: try with double slash instead of three slashes in file://C:official ......

Comment: Nop did not help same error

Comment: Can you show your pom?

Comment: Try the latest version of maven scm plugin 1.9.5 . Note you need to add plugin and not dependency.

Comment: 1.9.5 Still has same error .

Comment: First is the given git repo a bare repo? Furthermore you should define like this `file:///C:/official/gitrepo.git` (without the `/` before `.git`)...Is this the repo repo where you do your push to?

Comment: Yes I push to this repo and its a local repo

Comment: after making file:///C:/official/gitrepo.git it did not work same issue came